# How do I find out all the activities that have an onClickListener to a button in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, onclicklistener

I have a button labeled `dashButton` in my XML file. There are many activities, but I can't find what activity has the listener.

I have traced my way by looking at the intents from the activities to get to it by following my way as if I was navigating through the UI......
Is there any way to find out to find out what activity a button is linked through it's id?

Comment: To clarify: you have some `<Button>` tag in a layout file and you want to know what activity is responsible for handling clicks on that button? Are you using the `android:onClick` attribute in this tag?

Comment: Hint: the activity must somehow use the layout file, for example as a content view or as a list item view. Just search for its resource identifier.